# Chromium hangs using the TestCafe Docker image

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Attempting to run Chromium headless inside the testcafe/testcafe Docker image causes the browser to hang, no matter what options I've used. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
"browsers": {
    "path": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
    "cmd": "--headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox"
}
```

And the output after a few minutes:

```
e2e_1  | Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
e2e_1  | ERROR The HeadlessChrome 71.0.3578 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.
e2e_1  |
e2e_1  | Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

This works fine if I remove the `--headless`, but then the browser is rendering into Xvfb instead of running headlessly.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe

USER root

RUN apk --no-cache add \
    ffmpeg

RUN mkdir /home/e2e
WORKDIR /home/e2e
COPY . .
RUN chmod -R 757 /home/e2e

USER user

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1337 1338

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/e2e/testcafe-docker.sh"]
```

testcafe-docker.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH=${SCREEN_WIDTH-1280}
XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT=${SCREEN_HEIGHT-720}

dbus-daemon --session --fork
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 "${XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT}x24" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:1.0
fluxbox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
testcafe --ports 1337,1338 "$@"
```

.testcaferc.json:

```
{
    "browsers": "chromium --no-sandbox",
    "src": ["tests/*"],
    "reporter": "spec",
    "screenshotPath": "tmp/screenshots/",
    "screenshotPathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/test-${TEST_INDEX}/${USERAGENT}/${FILE_INDEX}.png",
    "takeScreenshotsOnFails": true,
    "videoPath": "tmp/reports/screen-captures",
    "videoOptions": {
        "singleFile": true,
        "failedOnly": true,
        "pathPattern": "${TEST_INDEX}/${USERAGENT}/${FILE_INDEX}.mp4"
    },
    "videoEncodingOptions": {
        "r": 20,
        "aspect": "16:9"
    },
    "skipJsErrors": true,
    "concurrency": 1,
    "port1": 1337,
    "port2": 1338
}
```

EDIT: I should correct myself that this does not work 100% of the time when I remove `--headless`, nor does it fail 100% of the time when it's headless. Either way, it intermittently passes one or two tests, and then fails. **Firefox does pass 100% of the time.** I've also been trying docker-compose a bit, but there's nothing too special in my docker-compose.yml, and the behavior seems the same.

Comment: Could you please provide the full command line by which you run tests inside the docker image?

Comment: I'm using the same entrypoint script as the official TestCafe Docker image. So all I'm doing is `docker-compose up`. My Dockerfile is based upon the official image, I'm just installing my own Node packages and using my own TestCafe config file, etc.

Comment: Could please share your docker image?

Comment: Thanks, added some clarification that this appears to be Chrome only, headless and rendered, and provided both the Dockerfile and the entrypoint script I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created an issue on the TestCafe GitHub about this. It ended up being resolved by using the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag on Chromium.

Issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3524

PR where this was made a default for running in Docker: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/3557

Answer (score 2):

[Updated] The latest TestCafe version (`1.1.4`) contains all the necessary flags.
You can simplify the `browsers` [property](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#browsers) value as follows:

```js
"browsers": "chromium"
```

Comment: Getting the same results, though TestCafe now explicitly states at the beginning that it's using Headless Chrome (though, it also referred to Headless Chrome in the original error as well).

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem without Docker?